# Shows the edges between the clipping plane and clipped objects

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader, fragment-shader

I want to utilize shaders to not only discard fragments if they are on one side of a predefined plane but also render a contour along the intersection.

My fragment shader currently does something along the lines of:

```
float dot = dot(world_coordinate, normalize(clipping_normal.xyz)) - clipping_normal.w;
if (dot > 0.0f) 
    discard;
```

this works but without the desired contour. I tried comparing the dot product against values close to 0.0 but this results in a contour with varying width depending on view etc...

This is what I am trying to achieve. Notice that the white contour/edge of where the plane intersects the sphere is of consistent width:

[image: cross-section]

So below is what the result I currently see:

[image: my-result]

With the fragment shader:

```
in vec4 color;
in vec3 world_position; 

out vec4 frag_color;

void main()
{    
    float dist = (dot(clipping_plane.xyz, world_position) - clipping_plane.w) / 
              dot(clipping_plane.xyz, clipping_plane.xyz);

    if(dist >= 0.0f && dist < 0.05f)
        frag_color = vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    else if(dist < 0.0f) 
        discard;
    else
        frag_color = ComputePhong(color);
}
```

Comment: Could you add an example of what you are looking for? Also: should it be exact or would an edge detection algorithm suffice?

Comment: I added an image, that should suffice or not?

Comment: No, what do you consider the contour? Isn't the white edge the contour?

Comment: Updated the question with more detail

Answer (score 1):

The contour of the intersection also belongs to the clipping plane, so the distance to this plane is zero.

Using `dot(point, normal)` is not enough. You need `d= A·x + B·y + C·z + D` which is the numerator (without "modulus") of the full distance point-to-plane formula. See [plane geometry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plane_(geometry)).

This calculated `d` gives you not only distance (add the square in the denominator if normal A,B,C is not unitary), but also its sign tells you which side of the plane the point is.

Working inside fragment shader likely you work with NDC coordinates. So transform `A,B,C,D` into NDC too.

Comment: I currently work with world coordinates in the fragment shader. Your approach gives a slightly better result but still doesn't fix the issue entirely unfortunately. The contour is not of consistent width and changes depending on the camera rotation. I can attach a link  with an image of the issue if needed.

Comment: @zman An Image is good, and with code, better. You may edit your question and add both.

Comment: Updated my question with more info.